# error when installing gcc

Tags: gcc

Whenever I try to install `gcc`, I get a bunch of 404 errors. I thought it might have been firewalls from 3rd party antivirus, but that wasn't the case. If it makes any difference I am running bash in windows 10. Anyone know any fixes?

```
sudo apt-get install gcc 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: libfreetype6 Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it. The following additional packages will be installed: 
binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev 
Suggested packages: binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc 
The following NEW packages will be installed: binutils cpp cpp-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev 

0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 

Need to get 5,297 kB/27.4 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 99.7 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Err:1  xenial-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.4 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
Err:2  xenial-security/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
Ign:3  xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-96.119 
Ign:4  xenial-security/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9 
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu./ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-96.119 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80] 
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using? Have you tried selecting a different server in *Software & Updates*?

Comment: looks like you arent connected to the internet or the server you have set for your repository is down .. you should check your connection and if its ok .. then change your repository

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` recently? If not, do it.

Comment: @JohnOrion No. If the remote host were unreachable, the error message would say that, not "file not found".